# Windows 8.1 account is partially deleted and blocking the creation of another account

Tags: windows-8.1

#### Probably all the information required

I have a Windows User Profile called David, which is linked to a Microsoft Account. I tried to delete it in the normal manner, which removed it from my log in options but kept its files and if I open a command prompt as Administrator:

`net user` this shows the account still exists.

`net user David /del` fails with error message "The group name could not be found".

#### Full Story

I have a Microsoft account that is linked to my Windows 8.1 machine. It has short name David. After updating to Windows 8.1 the OneDrive stopped working. I was getting an error saying it couldn't find the folder, then the error would go away but there was no syncing. I figured my profile settings were probably a bit messed up so I would just delete the account on the PC and re-create it. I deleted the account in the usual way, but it appears to have failed half way through the deletion process. The users/David folder is still there and the account still appears in the Computer Manager. The account does not appear as an option to sign into.

When I try to create the account again with my MS credentials, I am told "an account with that name already exists".

When I try to delete the account from the Computer Manager interface (WIN+X,R), I get an error: "The group name could not be found". When I right click on the user > Properties and try to select the 'Member Of' tab, I get the same error: "The group name could not be found".

I was able to delete it from the User Profiles list in System Properties (WIN + R:'sysdm.cpl' > Advanced Tab > User Profiles > Settings). Doing this deleted the account's user folder from C:\Users.

But it remained in the Computer Manager list of user profiles.

Opening a command prompt as Administrator:

`net user` shows the account
`net user David` shows the account information with a few suspicious entries. The last log in is wrong. I have used that account this week:

```
User name                    David
Full Name                    [fullName]
Comment                      
User's comment               
Country/region code          000 (System Default)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            8/14/2014 9:03:38 PM
Password expires             Never
Password changeable          8/14/2014 9:03:38 PM
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script                 
User profile                 
Home directory               
Last logon                   7/13/2013 9:05:04 PM

Logon hours allowed          All

Local Group Memberships      
The command completed with one or more errors.
```

So I am stuck.

Comment: Why don't you just create an entirely different username and link that, by doing so, you create a new linked user profile in the process.

Comment: Because many of the features in Windows 8.1 require you to log into the machine with your Windows ID.

Comment: Yes; I am saying create an entirely new local account ( I.e a different name ) then link that account to your Microsoft account

Comment: Tried that. If you create a local account and then link it, Windows will try to convert it to a Microsoft account and then fail, saying the email address has already been used on this computer.

Comment: Have you executed a full windows refresh?

Comment: No Windows refresh.